# Is it possible to identify the graphics program from the image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, graphics

Is there a good way to identify (or at least approximate) the graphics program used to obtain a particular image? For instance, I want to know if there is a certain signature that these programs embed into an image. Any suggestions?

If not, is there a reference where I can find what all meta-information can be extracted out of an image?

Comment: *"Zoom, enhance! The killer used Photoshop - I can tell from the pixels! Look up everyone who's bought Photoshop in the last 12 months!"* (More seriously, I'm curious as to why you want to do this.)

Comment: It occurred to me today when I was doing a search on Google for some image. I found many nearly identical images and was wondering if there is a way to determine which program created these. But good quote though! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain image file formats do have meta-data. It is format dependent. Digital cameras usually write some of their information into the meta-data. [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF) is what comes to mind. Images not acquired through a digital camera may or may not have relevant meta-data, so you can't consider meta-data of any sort to be a guaranteed reliable identifier. That's about as much as I can give as an answer, alas. I'm sure someone else may have more details.

Comment: And you also can't guarantee that any image processing done to an image which originally contained metadata, will be preserved in the output format

Comment: In particular, I believe Photoshop tends to preserve the EXIF data, but other image editing programs tend to mangle it. You can be damned sure that MS Paint doesn't preserve EXIF data, for example.

Comment: Ah... I was worried about the same. Thank you for the clarification.